# Controlling width of column from gt package with a function

Tags: r, function, gt

I am having trouble to control the width of my gt tables with this function I created.

Any help?

```
cols_fn <- function(data, y){
data %>%
    select(1:4) %>%
    gt() %>%
    gt_theme_espn() %>% cols_width(4 ~ paste0(glue::glue({y}),"px"))

}

cols_fn(mtcars,y = 900)
```

I have this error message: `Error in force(..1) : object 'y' not found`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach to make your function work would be to use `as.formula` like so:

```
library(gt)
library(gtExtras)
library(dplyr)

cols_fn <- function(data, y) {
  data %>%
    select(1:4) %>%
    gt() %>%
    gt_theme_espn() %>%
    cols_width(as.formula(glue::glue("4~px({y})")))
}

cols_fn(head(mtcars), y = 900)
```

[image]